# send both JSON data and an image with router.get to react frontend from nodejs back end

Tags: node.js, json, express

I'm trying to send an image and JSON data to the front end from my node.js back end. I use router.get for this and I'm able to send both the image and the data seperatly but I can't seem to send them both with the same request.

to send just the image I used the following code:

```
router.get("/userdata/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  console.log(id);

  const userinfo = await Users.findOne({
    where: { id: id },
    attributes: { exclude: ["password", "emailverification"] },
  });
  res.set("Content-Type", ïmage/png");
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "..", userinfo.pfp));
});
```

and to send the json data I used the following code:

```
router.get("/userdata/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  console.log(id);

  const userinfo = await Users.findOne({
    where: { id: id },
    attributes: { exclude: ["password", "emailverification"] },
  });
  res.json(userinfo)
});
```

I tried to combine to combine the codes to send both the image and the JSON and used this code:

```
router.get("/userdata/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  console.log(id);

  const userinfo = await Users.findOne({
    where: { id: id },
    attributes: { exclude: ["password", "emailverification"] },
  });
  res.set("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "..", userinfo.pfp), userinfo);
  res.json(userinfo)
});
```

but here I get only the JSON data and when I remove the `res.json(userinfo)` I only get the following error: `Failed to parse multipart response: content-type missing boundary` inside insomnia (the program I use to test this).

does anyone know how i can do this?
thanks in advance

Comment: It's two different content types, so you'll probably need to represent your image as a string (data URI) and add it as part of the JSON structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Amy suggested in the comments, you will need to use one content type for the response.

Using the json is the more appropriate approach and you can convert the image to a base64 encoded URI and send that in the response.

I've added a util function for the conversion and also updated the response object to send both the user's json info and the base64 encoded image URI.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const util = require("util");

const readFileAsync = util.promisify(fs.readFile);

// util function to get the base64 encoded string for passed image.
async function getImageBase64(filePath) {
  const image = await readFileAsync(filePath);
  const buffer = Buffer.from(image);
  return `data:image/png;base64,${buffer.toString("base64")}`;
}

router.get("/userdata/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  console.log(id);

  const userinfo = await Users.findOne({
    where: { id: id },
    attributes: { exclude: ["password", "emailverification"] },
  });

  const imageURI = await getImageBase64(path.join(__dirname, "..", userinfo.pfp));

  res.json({
    userInfo: userinfo,
    imageURI: imageURI,
  });
});
```

Comment: yes this worked!! I treid it an other way my self with a library called image-to-uri but the iro O get from this is much longer. whats the diffirance?

Comment: @Tijmi. I can't say why the library didn't work for you and why it provides a different result than the code in the answer, as I haven't used that package myself. 
The code I provided I have already tested and used in projects, and also does not require any external packages.

Comment: I meant that the uri was much shorter, it still worked the uri for image was just way shorter than with your code and I was wondering why that was, like is it because it lowers the quality or something?